# add crosshair to charts in a winform project

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I just started with charts in C# and the problem is, I don't know How can I add crosshair to charts? My project is a winform application using C#.

Comment: interesting question .. even i wondered if its possible

Comment: @V4Vendetta : I have found some solutions, but all of them are laggy...

Comment: Do you mean the `this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;`?

Comment: I explained this throughly in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440894/how-to-make-the-cursor-lines-to-follow-the-mouse-in-charts-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thx to every one but I found the solution as below:

```
cursor_Y = Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorY;
cursor_X = Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX;
cursor_Y.LineWidth = 2;
cursor_Y.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
cursor_Y.LineColor = Color.Red;
cursor_Y.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;

cursor_X.LineWidth = 2;
cursor_X.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
cursor_X.LineColor = Color.Red;

Chart1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Chart1_MouseMove);
...
PointF _point = new PointF(2,2);

void Chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _point.X = e.Location.X;
    _point.Y = e.Location.Y;

    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(_point, true);
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(_point, true);
}
```

Comment: I can't make this draw the horizontal line. It only draws the vertical.

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough, just override the chart's OnPaint method, or subscribe to the Paint event and also to the chart's MouseMove event.

So you'd have something like:

```
Point MouseLocation;

private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseLocation = e.Location;
    Invalidate();
}

private void Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, MouseLocation.Y), new Point(Width, MouseLocation.Y));
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(MouseLocation.X, 0), new Point(MouseLocation.X, Height));
}
```

To make it a lot smoother, you need to look into double-buffering and setting the lines in a region and invalidate just the region needing redrawing.

Also to make dashed lines look into creating your own Pen.

Comment: the problem is, the lines must be inside the charts only and charts don't have drawline... so how do I drawline in side a chart?

Comment: put the chart in another control, like a panel and draw on the panel.

Comment: thx Chuck but I found an easier way. I post it below.

Comment: you can use PaintEventArgs.Graphics to draw

Answer (score -1):

Just create two label box as **lab_X_Axis** and **lab_Y_Axis**.
In chart mousemove function code as shown below..

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lab_X_Axis.Location = new Point((e.X), 21);
    lab_Y_Axis.Location = new Point(76, e.Y);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lab_X_Axis.AutoSize = false;
    lab_Y_Axis.AutoSize = false;
    lab_X_Axis.Text="";
    lab_Y_Axis.Text="";
    lab_X_Axes.Size = new Size(1, 300);
    lab_Y_Axes.Size = new Size(300, 1);
}
```

Comment: This is a very clunky and inefficient method, and considering the answer the OP posted almost *3 years ago*, it doesn't even seem relevant.